# How to use :not selector on click event?

Tags: jquery

First I tried like this:

```
$('.choose-car li:not(.selected)').click(function () {
    console.log('works and with selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Then I thought a litle and and tried like this:

```
$('.choose-car li:not(.selected)').on('click', function () {
    console.log('works and with selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

both works with selected..

But now I thinking maybe I have to remove click event after first click or is there easier solution? Maybe I missing something?

Comment: What's the problem? While you're at it, show the markup and a brief description of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I dont want to see `console.log('works and with selected');` on second click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is adding the `selected` class after you register the handler. This is probably not what you want, since the handler will remain bound to the element even after it acquires the `selected` class.

Try delegating the event instead:

```
$(".choose-car").on("click", "li:not(.selected)", function() {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".choose-car" ).on( "click", "li", function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass("selected") ) {
        return;
    }

     $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
$(this).removeClass('selected')
}
else{
$(this).addClass('selected')
}
```